# Store the ids in an array in session in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page full of images. Now I want to add button "Like" on every image in the page. I want on clicking these buttons, the ids of the images get captured in an array.
So that afterwards I can store this array in the session variable so that I can access this data from anywhere in the website without storing it in the database table. The project is developed in Codeigniter.

Comment: You will need ajax to do that

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use ajax 
Give the like button a name and then in jquery make it on click event.

```
<button class="like">LIKE BUTTON</button>

$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.like').on('click',function(){

        YOUR AJAX CODE HERE 

   })

})
```

In controller 
GET your ajax value and insert those into a session.
I know this code is not that something you are looking for but it's just an idea.